# How to pass data from textfield to url in function

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct PostModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let url: String
}

class DownloadWithCombineViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts: [PostModel] = []
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        getPosts()
    }
    
    func getPosts() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://example\(inputText)")
        else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .tryMap(handleOutput)
            .decode(type: PostModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: PostModel(id: "", url: ""))
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedPosts in
                self?.posts = [returnedPosts]
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func handleOutput(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output) throws -> Data {
        guard
            let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return output.data
    }
}
struct ResultView: View {
    
    @State var inputText = ""
    @State var showResult = false
    @StateObject var vm = DownloadWithCombineViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter", text: $inputText)
                
                Button("Show Result") {
                    
                    showResult.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
                if showResult {
                   
                    List {
                        ForEach(vm.posts) { post in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(post.url)
                                    .font(.headline)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried different options, but still does not see inputText. It is possible to do this??

Comment: Add an argument to getPosts instead of using the variable from the class

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple approach where you have `func getPosts(inputText: String)` and use
`.onSubmit {...}` (that is press return) on the `TextField` to action the `getPosts` function.

```
struct PostModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let url: String
}

class DownloadWithCombineViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts: [PostModel] = []
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func getPosts(inputText: String) {  // <--- here
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://example\(inputText)")
        else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .tryMap(handleOutput)
            .decode(type: PostModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: PostModel(id: "", url: ""))
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedPosts in
                self?.posts = [returnedPosts]
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func handleOutput(output: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output) throws -> Data {
        guard
            let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return output.data
    }
}

struct ResultView: View {
    @State var inputText = ""
    @State var showResult = false
    @StateObject var vm = DownloadWithCombineViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter", text: $inputText)
                    .onSubmit {  // <--- here
                        vm.getPosts(inputText: inputText)  // <--- here
                    }
                Button("Show Result") {
                    showResult.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                
                if showResult {
                    List (vm.posts) { post in  // <--- here
                        Text(post.url)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```